# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

Yes, I did my research and as far as I can find so far I am unable to figure out why seemingly out of nowhere the product tabs are no longer functioning as expected. In the Console, I see:

```
app.js:932 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function
```

We noticed this after updating from Magento 1.9.3.3(ish) to 1.9.3.6 (Now 1.9.3.8). We use the RWD theme as the parent theme, and have a custom theme on top of it. There are two jQuery libraries, but if I take away jQuery 1.11.0.min.js parts of the layout of the product page disappear.

It would be much appreciated if you can help me with this odd situation.

Here are all the scripts when they are loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/css/nwdthemes/ultratabs_base_default.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/varien/product_options.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/varien/configurable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/video/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/video/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/video/masonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/video/html5lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/video/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/fileuploader/filepop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/matchMedia.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/matchMedia.addListener.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/js/nwdthemes/enquire.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/selectivizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/matchMedia.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/enquire.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/minicart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/<removed>2/default/js/readmore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/js/et_advancedcompare/noreload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/magehit_bestseller/js/noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/magehit_bestseller/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/magehit_newproducts/js/noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/magehit_newproducts/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/js/flexibleblog/general.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/js/flexibleforms/jquery-noconflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/js/flexibleforms/stars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/<removed>2/default/js/image-hijacker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/nwdthemes/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/nwdthemes/revslider/public/assets/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<removed>/skin/frontend/base/default/js/nwdthemes/ultratabs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Also, a lot of the solutions I found for other similar issues ask for say replace "$" with "$j", but as you may now in the no-confict.js files for RWD theme there's already an implementation of that.

**Updated:** 
Here's the code within app.js (RWD Theme) that is being complained about. I put a comment before the line where it errors out. I am very confused on hwo to fix this issue.

```
// ==============================================
// UI Pattern - Toggle Content (tabs and accordions in one setup)
// ==============================================

$j('.toggle-content').each(function () {
    var wrapper = jQuery(this);

    var hasTabs = wrapper.hasClass('tabs');
    var hasAccordion = wrapper.hasClass('accordion');
    var startOpen = wrapper.hasClass('open');

    var dl = wrapper.children('dl:first');
    var dts = dl.children('dt');
    var panes = dl.children('dd');
    var groups = new Array(dts, panes);

    //Create a ul for tabs if necessary.
    if (hasTabs) {
        var ul = jQuery('<ul class="toggle-tabs"></ul>');
        dts.each(function () {
            var dt = jQuery(this);
            var li = jQuery('<li></li>');
            li.html(dt.html());
            ul.append(li);
        });
        ul.insertBefore(dl);
        var lis = ul.children();
        groups.push(lis);
    }

    //Add "last" classes.
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        groups[i].filter(':last').addClass('last');
    }

    function toggleClasses(clickedItem, group) {
        var index = group.index(clickedItem);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            groups[i].removeClass('current');
            groups[i].eq(index).addClass('current');
        }
    }

    //Toggle on tab (dt) click.
    dts.on('click', function (e) {
        //They clicked the current dt to close it. Restore the wrapper to unclicked state.
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('current') && wrapper.hasClass('accordion-open')) {
            wrapper.removeClass('accordion-open');
        } else {
            //They're clicking something new. Reflect the explicit user interaction.
            wrapper.addClass('accordion-open');
        }
        toggleClasses(jQuery(this), dts);
    });

    //Toggle on tab (li) click.
    if (hasTabs) {
        lis.on('click', function (e) {
//This line here is where it errors.
            toggleClasses(jQuery(this), lis);
        });
        //Open the first tab.
        lis.eq(0).trigger('click');
    }

    //Open the first accordion if desired.
    if (startOpen) {
        dts.eq(0).trigger('click');
    }

});
```

Comment: Okay, interesting. I'll play with removing a jQuery library and see what my results are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT post comment from Kevin...

**Change**

`jQuery(...)`

**To**

`$j(...)`

Comment: Okay, so the no-conflict variable for the first libary is
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); then nwdthemes noconflict has ;var $nwd_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);

Comment: @KevinKeeney Cool, simply change the first one back to jQuery and everything should work fine.

Comment: To be clear, $j was the variable that was assigned the no conflict, and the console isn't complaining about that variable rather jQuery within a JS block. I'll edit the original question to reflect the app.js code the console is complaining about. This confuses me.